# Loading a BMP in an Eclipse Plugin Perspective using SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a BMP in a bytearray.  I would like to display the BMP in an Eclipse Plugin using SWT.

If I want to display the BMP using swing - it can be done as follows:

```
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
    try {
        bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(getLocalByteArray()));
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }

    JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bufferedImage));

    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    jPanel.add(jLabel);
    this.add(jPanel);
```

Update:
The BMP will be represented as a byte array. This is pre requisite of this.

How do I do this in an Eclipse Plugin using SWT?  Note I am using a Perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I figured it out.  As the code is short I've included the context:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(getLocalByteArray()));
        ImageData imageData = new ImageData(inputStream);
        Image image = ImageDescriptor.createFromImageData(imageData).createImage();


        // Create the canvas for drawing
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas( parent, SWT.NONE);
        canvas.addPaintListener( new PaintListener() {
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        GC gc = e.gc;
        gc.drawImage( image,10,10);
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

An SWT `Image` can directly be created from an input stream. Several data formats are supported, including Windows format BMPs.

For example:

```java
Image image = new Image( display, new ByteArrayInputStream( ... ) );
```

The resulting image can then be set on a `Label` or used elsewhere.

Comment: Apologies. I've updated my question. The BMP being represented as a byte array is a pre requisite. Thanks.

Comment: Please re-read the answered. It creates an Image from a (ByteArray) InputStream. Replace the ... with your method call and you are done. And don't forget to dispose of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply specify the file in the `Image` constructor and then set it to a `Label`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    Image image = new Image(display, "image.bmp");
    label.setImage(image);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();

    image.dispose();
}
```

Remember that you have to `dispose()` of the image yourself to not create a memory leak.

Comment: Apologies. I've updated my question. The BMP being represented as a byte array is a pre requisite. Thanks.